# Changing FontWeight of Header content by trigger in TabControl

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to change FontWeight of `Header` property of `TabItem` in `TabControl` when `TabItem` is selected. I wrote this code:

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Bottom">
 <TabControl.Resources>
  <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
   <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
    <Setter.Value>
     <DataTemplate>
      <ContentPresenter>
       <ContentPresenter.Content>
        <TextBlock FontSize="18" Padding="5,0,0,0" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}">
         <TextBlock.Style>
          <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
           <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
               <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
             </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
          </Style>
         </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>
       </ContentPresenter.Content>
      </ContentPresenter>
     </DataTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
  </Style>
 </TabControl.Resources>
 ...
</TabControl>
```

This code works but seems excess and bulky.

Is there a way to shorten this code without codebehind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<ContentPresenter>` in this case is unnecessary (signle TextBlock can be root item of a template): minus 4 tags

Trigger can be used on TabItem: minus another 4 tags

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock FontSize="18" Padding="5,0,0,0" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" Value="SemiBold"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

in case if it is not appropriate to make entire header SemiBold after selection, then make use of DataTemplate triggers:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TabItem}}">
    <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock x:Name="HeaderText" FontSize="18" Padding="5,0,0,0" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>

                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TabItem}}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="TextElement.FontWeight" TargetName="HeaderText" Value="SemiBold"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: `TabItem` trigger does not affect the `Header` FontWeight. I've tried this way earlier.